# Got the notification to update Facebook graph API from v12 to v13

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am not using Facebook graph APIs, but got the notification to update the version from v12 to v13. Do I need to update this on Facebook console or not required.

tried to do from Facebook console. Wanted to ask, if I need to do or not required to do anything, it will update automatically.

Comment: You must be using a Facebook app id for _something_, otherwise why should you get such a notification to begin with. If you are not actively using any functionality that makes custom API calls anywhere, but only use the app id to embed social plugins, then you probably don't need to update anything, stuff should continue to work.